# Display brightness is not changed by changing brightness file

Tags: display, brightness, xrandr

I recently re-installed Ubuntu 21.10 on my laptop and found that Fn+F5/F6 don't work for adjusting the display brightness. I've had this problem before and usually just run

```
xrandr --output DP-2 --brightness <brightness>
```

Now this returns

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
warning: output DP-2 not found; ignoring
xrandr: Need crtc to set gamma on.
```

The so I ran `xrandr --verbose` to get the possible output names, but it only has info for 'Screen 0', no actual display names. It also threw the error

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

I tried both solutions to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391669/xrandr-displaying-failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-output-default) but they did not work.

I also got the error from `xrandr` `xrandr: Need crtc to set gamma on.`, but couldn't really find any concrete way to fix this.

After more research I found that the current brightness is stored in `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`, which seems really great because then I could just write a script that modifies that directly.

Unfortunately, I've discovered that not only does rewriting the brightness file do nothing to the actual brightness, pressing Fn+F5/F6 decrements/increments the value stored in that file. So somehow whichever program is *actually* controlling the brightness is not reading that file, but I'm out of ideas on how to fix it at this point.

Comment: Are you booted into Wayland or XOrg?

Comment: @Terrance XOrg.

Comment: Check your list of monitors: `xrandr --listactivemonitors`